# $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{a+\cos(x)}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have been trying to solve the integral below using contour integration.
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{a+\cos(x)}dx, \quad a>1.$$

I'd appreciate to see how you would solve it, since the fact that it goes to only $\pi$ and not to $2\pi$ gives me some complications when solving for the residues, after using the variable change $y=2x$.

Comment: I presume you mean $dx$, not $dt$.  Note that the integrand is an even function, thus you can integrate from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and divide by $2$.

Comment: Oh true, ill give that a try. Thanks

Comment: Use this substitution https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstraß-Substitution

Answer (score 3):

The chances of me saying this were high: let us avoid contour integration.
By symmetry
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{a+\cos\theta}\,d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^2(\theta)\left[\frac{1}{a+\cos\theta}+\frac{1}{a-\cos\theta}\right]d\theta$$
equals
$$ 2a\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{a^2-\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta\stackrel{\theta\mapsto\arctan t}{=}2a\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)(a^2+(a^2-1)t^2)} $$
or
$$ \frac{\pi}{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}} $$
by partial fraction decomposition.